# XSLT SUM() not working as expected

Tags: xslt, xpath, sum

I've been trying to get the sum (total) value for elements in different nodes, but after a week messing around with example after example I am no step closer to the solution.

All I get is the different values listed in a string rather than the sum.

The selection used to get the values is:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//workgroups/workgroup/agentstatus/status">
  <xsl:if test="key='Available, No ACD'">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(value)"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This returns `111` rather than the expected value `3`

What do I do wrong here?

This is xml version="1.0" encoding='utf-8'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//workgroups/workgroup/agentstatus/status[./key/text()='Available, No ACD']/value)" />
```

The looping's taken care of by the way XSLT works, so you don't need to specify a for each or an if statement - it's all implied by the xpath statement.
If this doesn't work please can you post a copy of the XML you're running it on and I'll then update the xpath as required.

Comment: Fantastic! An answer in 49 seconds and it solves my struggle totally!

Comment: No worries - please give me a shout if you have any trouble understanding the above code.  XSLT's hard to get your head around when you first come to it from other languages, but code solidly in it for a few days and something clicks after which everything gets easy and you start to love it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code select *all* status elements and then for each that have the desired key value, it outputs sum(value). So, the summary runs separately for each `status` hit with `xsl:if`.

You should use:

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="sum(//workgroups/workgroup/agentstatus
                   /status[key/text()='Available, No ACD']/value)"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the difference between [./key/text()=

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what is the difference between [./key/text()= and  [/key/text()=  I'm not sure but would the ./ not use the location from the current excising path as where /key uses the path from the top?

Comment: Note that I never wrote `[/key...` which really goes from the top, and would refer to a hypothetic <key> document-element (the only root). I wrote `[key` and JohnLBevan wrote `[./key` which are interchangeable. The . node is the context node which happens to be the same context that is assumed one a nested XPath, like the condition starting in the bracket, begins.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I've had a fight with the editor (as you can see by my first failed attempt) Just wanted to make sure that I did understand the [./key and [key referred to the same thing. Thanks for confirming!